# how to get more than 200 results for a single query in Rally WSAPI

Tags: rally, agile-central

Is there a way to increase the pageSize per AJAX call to webservice API in Rally.I need to display the task count per team member in a given project.I can do it my making continuous AJAX calls to retreive the tasks per team member.Suppose if there are 80 people working on this project I need to make 80 calls to WebService API.Another Approach I thought of is to get all the tasks of all the team members using single query and then filter the results according to the owners of the tasks but this approach will only return  the first 200 tasks since there is a limit on the pageSize. How can I get all the results in a single Query?

Comment: There's a bunch of stuff about Rally in Google.  How about helping us out by 1.  Posting your code, and 2.  Providing a link to the relevant documentation?  If Rally says they only return 200 results, then it is what it is.

Comment: Sorry your question was the victim of overzealous moderating.  The maximum page size per request is 200.  After that you have to page using start=201.  Since you mentioned ajax you are probably using one of our App SDK's?  They should manage paging for you.  I suggest opening a new question with a code snippet asking how to do paging in the App SDK so we can help you and future visitors can find it as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using one of our App SDK's?

http://developer.help.rallydev.com/app-sdk

In 1.x [RallyDataSource](http://developer.help.rallydev.com/rally-data-source).findAll will automatically page for you and return all results.
There are good examples of how to use it [here](http://developer.help.rallydev.com/data-examples).

In 2.0 preview the [WsapiDataStore](http://developer.help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0p5/doc/#!/api/Rally.data.WsapiDataStore-cfg-limit) has a limit parameter you can set to Infinity or some other large maximum number of results to return.

Examples:
http://developer.help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0p5/doc/#!/guide/appsdk_20_data_stores